# cakephp requestHandler check for swf/flash

Tags: cakephp, flash, requesthandler

Is there a way to check if a cakePHP action is being called from an swf/flash movie like there is for Ajax using the requestHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Put a named parameter in the URL that Flash is requesting:

eg. `http://www.example.com/controller/action/flash:true`

Check for this named parameter in your controller (or AppController) code:

```
if (isset($this->params['named']['flash'])) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.  A better option might be to create discrete controller actions that you only use from your Flash app.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way I think you mean. The `requestHandler` can detect the *type* of request, but I think you're looking for the request *source*. It might be worth trying the `getReferrer()` method, but you may end up needing to add a click handler to the swf (if it's yours and you have that access).